# Sequelize Query in Nest.JS not resolving before return

Tags: node.js, promise, sequelize.js, nestjs, sequelize-typescript

I have a function that gets an order from a database, creates an object from the response, gets a response from the db for all the line items and loops over those item to get detail records.  The problem I am having is that the overall function is returning even though I am trying to await the response from the subqueries.

Code as follows:

```
public async getOrderById(orderId:string) {
    const order: [any] = await this.dbInstance.query('exec getOrder :orderID' {replacements: {orderID: orderId}, type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT});
    const orderLines: [any] = await this.dbInstance.query('exec getOrderLines :orderID' {replacements: {orderID: orderId}, type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT});

    const orderArray: any = order.map((o) => { 
         return {
            orderId,
            customerId: o.CustomerID
            total: o.total,
            lines: []
          };
    });

    const orderResponse: Order = orderArray[0];

    orderLines.forEach(async (orderLine) => { 
         let addItem: any;
         addItem = {
                itemNumber: orderLine.itemNumber,
                quantity: orderLine.quantity,
                unitPrice: orderLine.unitPrice,
                orderLineDetails: []
         };

        await this.dbInstance.query('exec getLineDetails :orderLineId{replacements: {orderLineId: orderLine.orderLineId}, type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
         .then( (details) => { 
             details.forEach((detail) => {
                addItem.orderLineDetails.push({
                    name: detail.name,
                    value: detail.val
                });
             });
         });

        orderResponse.orderLines.push(addItem);
    });

    return orderResponse;

}
```

So the code will get into the forEach on the order Lines, create the add Item, but then it will push the addItem before waiting for the result of the orderLineDetails to be created and added to the orderLineDetails array.  If I let the whole thing run, the breakpoint with the push for the orderLineDetails will run a second after the response has already returned.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was the method I was using to perform the mappings (forEach) which was not asynchronous, along with modifying the underlying collection in the loop.

I ended up making this change:

```
const orderLinePromises = orderLines.map(async (orderLine) => { 
    let addItem : any;

     addItem = {
            itemNumber: orderLine.itemNumber,
            quantity: orderLine.quantity,
            unitPrice: orderLine.unitPrice,
            orderLineDetails: []
     };

     const details = await this.dbInstance.query('exec getLineDetails :orderLineId{replacements: {orderLineId: orderLine.orderLineId}, type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT});
      addItem.orderLineDetails = details.map((detail) => {
            return {
               name: detail.name,
               value: detail.val,
            };
      );

     return addItem;

});

orderResponse.orderLines = await Promise.all(orderLinePromises);

return orderResponse;
```